# Is it correct to use raw SQL requests in some cases?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I filled my database with about 25K records, I noticed that my application started working slowly. I've checked out the logs and realize that instead of one SQL request ActiveRecord is performing more that eight. I have rewritten the code to use one SQL request, and it has speeded my application up minimum in two times.

So, is it correct to write raw SQL requests in parts of application that is heavily loaded?

Comment: One problem could be, that you become DB-dependend. So try to avoid very special SQL-commands (or accept the dependency). But beside this: Yes.

Comment: This is a question that lead more to dicussion than to answers which can be accepted as right answer. Stack Overflow is most effective if you do not use it as discussion platform.

Comment: I have seen database table with billions of records answering request within milliseconds... I would argue that if your database slows down with only 25k record then your database or your queries are missing some very basic optimization technics like adding indexes to your tables, [eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) or your database structure simply does not match the requirements. I would investigate the root cause of your problems before I use raw SQL.

Comment: rewrite your question, give us your problem, give us your solution, and people can check if their is a better solution using just activerecord.

Comment: @knut ActiveRecord doesn't help with database portability in any useful way. Consider all the questions about "this worked at in SQLite but fell apart at Heroku in PostgreSQL". You don't have to get into anything fancy to run into problems, a simple GROUP BY or LIKE will cause trouble.

Comment: @muistooshort I was not aware of this.  think I know, why I decided in the past, why I selected sequel and not ActiveRecord. Beside some topics I had no problems to switch between SQlite and MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Some times you need to [eager load](http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) your data. Other times you really need to write raw SQL queries

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes correct to use raw SQL, as ActiveRecord and Arel do not easily allow the full SQL syntax to be used, and sometimes it is helpful to just express a scope as a raw SQL fragment, but it is not correct for the first response to a performance problem to be the use of raw SQL.

It would be better to explore eager loading and joining methods, and other options, before using raw SQL, as you may be making your application less flexible to changes in future.

If you post the code that is causing the problem and the SQL being generated by it, then you may get useful advice on how to avoid raw SQL.

Comment: Re "it is not correct to respond to a performance problem by reaching for raw SQL". Consider a recursive query, using a recursive CTE (i.e. `WITH RECURSIVE`) can give you massive performance benefits over doing the recursion by hand. Window functions can also give you big performance gains. Never mind types that that aren't universally supported by databases or AR's interpretation of SQL. All those things push you into SQL. Yes, you can use Arel to avoid writing SQL but only a madman (or a sadist) writes Arel by hand.

Comment: @muistooshort I tweaked the wording slightly to better express myself. It's certainly true that SQL can be a huge performance gain -- I have a PostgreSQL stored procedure in my Rails app with a 400 line SQL statement in it -- but I'd advise exhausting all reasonable Rails-based alternatives first.